# CSS Don't select the first element inside a div with mixed content

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have mixed content inside each

box, what I need is to select all the images except the first one it finds. I have tried in different ways but I can't get it, can you help me? below I leave the code

```
<style>
  img{ width:50px; height:50px; }
  
  /* apply border to all but first image  */
  /*p:not(p:first-of-type) > img{
    border:2px solid red 
  }*/
   
  /*p > :not(:first-of-type > img) {
    border:2px solid red 
  }*/
  /*p:not(p > img:nth-of-type(1)){
    border:1px solid red 
  }*/
  /*img:not(:nth-of-type(1)) {
    border:1px solid red;
  }*/
  /* *:not(img:first-of-type){
    border: 1px solid red;
  }*/
  /* *:not(img:first-of-type) > img {
    border: 1px solid red;
  }*/
  /* :not(*:first-of-type) img{
    border: 1px solid red;
  }*/ 
  *:not(:first-of-type > img) > img {
    border: 1px solid red;
  }
</style>
<p>hello</p>
<p>hello</p>
<p>hello</p>
<p>hello</p>
<p><img src="https://static.jsbin.com/images/dave.min.svg"></p>
<p>hello</p>
<p>hello</p>
<p>hello</p>

<p><img src="https://static.jsbin.com/images/dave.min.svg"></p>
<p>hello</p>
<p><img src="https://static.jsbin.com/images/dave.min.svg"></p>
<p>hello</p>
<p><img src="https://static.jsbin.com/images/dave.min.svg"></p>
<p>hello</p>
<p><img src="https://static.jsbin.com/images/dave.min.svg"></p>
<p>hello</p>
<p><img src="https://static.jsbin.com/images/dave.min.svg"></p>
<p>hello</p>
<p><img src="https://static.jsbin.com/images/dave.min.svg"></p>
```

DEMO: https://jsbin.com/vawumehime/1/edit?html,output

Comment: For that particular markup, what you need is `:nth-child(n + 2 of p:has(img)) img` but there's no Firefox support for that yet, and it's not clear whether it would be suitable for more representative markup.

Comment: How representative is the code you have now given? eg could there be an img not within a p element, or could there be an img as a great grandchild and so on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox supports the CSS :has selector only if the user has set a flag.

Other major browsers support it by default and so this will work:

```
*:has(> img) ~ * img
```

```html
<style>
  img {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
  }
  
  *:has(> img)~* img {
    border: solid 1px red;
  }
</style>
<p>hello</p>
<p>hello</p>
<p>hello</p>
<p>hello</p>
<p><img src="https://static.jsbin.com/images/dave.min.svg"></p>
<p>hello</p>
<p>hello</p>
<p>hello</p>

<p><img src="https://static.jsbin.com/images/dave.min.svg"></p>
<p>hello</p>
<p><img src="https://static.jsbin.com/images/dave.min.svg"></p>
<p>hello</p>
<p><img src="https://static.jsbin.com/images/dave.min.svg"></p>
<p>hello</p>
<p><img src="https://static.jsbin.com/images/dave.min.svg"></p>
<p>hello</p>
<p><img src="https://static.jsbin.com/images/dave.min.svg"></p>
<p>hello</p>
<p><img src="https://static.jsbin.com/images/dave.min.svg"></p>
```

That is, select every img that is in an element that is somewhere preceded by (is a sibling of) an element that contains an img element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `:nth-child()` selector to select all but the first two `<p>` tags:

```css
img{ width:50px; height:50px; }

p:nth-child(n+3) > img {
  border:2px solid red 
}
```

```html
<p>hello</p>
<p><img src="https://static.jsbin.com/images/dave.min.svg"></p>
<p>hello</p>
<p><img src="https://static.jsbin.com/images/dave.min.svg"></p>
<p>hello</p>
<p><img src="https://static.jsbin.com/images/dave.min.svg"></p>
<p>hello</p>
<p><img src="https://static.jsbin.com/images/dave.min.svg"></p>
<p>hello</p>
<p><img src="https://static.jsbin.com/images/dave.min.svg"></p>
<p>hello</p>
<p><img src="https://static.jsbin.com/images/dave.min.svg"></p>
<p>hello</p>
<p><img src="https://static.jsbin.com/images/dave.min.svg"></p>
```

Comment: Hello, this solution is only if the content has that order, I just updated the post to make the exercise a little more dynamic